# Make object's destructor not call member's destructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, destructor

I want to store my objects in a vector. But when I clear the vector, I want the object destructor to be called, but I do not want some of it's members destructors to not be called? How can I achieve this?

```
class Officer
{
public:
    CPed* m_pOfficer;
    CVehicle* m_pPatrolVeh;
    char m_pCallSign[16];
    unsigned short m_nUnitNum;
}
```

I don't want m_pOfficer and m_pPatrolVeh destructors to be called.

Comment: I don't know why you want to do that but if you don't call `delete m_pOfficer;` in the destructor of `Officer`, they will not be deleted when an instance of `Officer` gets deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these 2 statements...

```
delete m_pOfficer;
delete m_pPatrolVeh;
```

... are absent inside the destructor of Officer then whatever was pointed to by these pointers will not be destroyed at the destruction of Officer objects. The question is, do you have something else be pointing to that data?

From a design point of view, this does not something that would be encouraged. Maybe you can tell us more about what your aim is.

Comment: My code is getting injected into a game. So CPed and CVehicle are classes created by the game. I don't want to delete them because the game still has the handle of them, and it will crash the game. So, I want to destruct the Officer class without touching the CPed and CVehicle pointers because the hand will take care of those.

Comment: Yeah, as long as you don't call delete on those classes inside the destructor, there should be no problem at least in theory.